# reverse_geocoder not functioning properly when trying to track ISS

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I try to use the `reverse_geocoder` library to track the ISS ( in conjunction with ephem ) I get severely mismatched countries, and the coordinates don't change at all ( with a 10-sec sleep in a while true ), which shouldn't be happening, considering that the coordinates ephem returns are correct ( to ~1 degree ).

Here is the code I use for the coordinates only, which works:

```
import ephem
import time

name = "ISS (ZARYA)"
line1 = "1 25544U 98067A   19357.29284137 -.00000119  00000-0  59685-5 0  9991"
line2 = "2 25544  51.6427 143.8164 0007706  64.3789  19.8690 15.50124701204590"

while True:
    iss = ephem.readtle(name, line1, line2)
    iss.compute()
    print ( iss.sublat, iss.sublong )
    time.sleep(5)
```

And here is the code I use with reverse_geocoder:

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
import time
from ephem import readtle, degree

name = "ISS (ZARYA)"
line1 = "1 25544U 98067A   19357.29284137 -.00000119  00000-0  59685-5 0  9991"
line2 = "2 25544  51.6427 143.8164 0007706  64.3789  19.8690 15.50124701204590"

iss = readtle(name, line1, line2)
while True:
    iss.compute()
    pos = (iss.sublat / degree, iss.sublong / degree)
    location = rg.search(pos)
    print(location)
    time.sleep(10)
```

( You have to end these programs yourself, they'll run forever otherwise )

The second program continuously returned a location in Andorra, while the ISS was near Australia; also, the coordinates `reverse_geocoder` returned never change, which isn't normal at all.

What can I do in order to make the second code work, considering that the coordinates it's receiving are correct?

Update: after checking the table from which `reverse_geocoder` finds the name, I found out that the Andorran city it prints is exactly the first element on the list. The `rg.search` command literally doesn't bother going past the first element.